# Calculate subtotals with dplyr and tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
expand.grid(country = c('Sweden','Norway', 'Denmark','Finland'),
            sport = c('curling','crosscountry','downhill')) %>% 
    mutate(medals = sample(0:3, 12, TRUE)) -> 
 data
```

Using reshape2's dcast achieves this in one line. Using custom names for the margins require extra steps.

```
library(reshape2)

data %>% 
  dcast(country ~  sport, margins = TRUE, sum) %>% 

 # optional renaming of the margins `(all)`
  rename(Total = `(all)`) %>% 
  mutate(country = ifelse(country == "(all)", "Total", country))
```

My dplyr + tidyr approach is verbose. What is the best (compact and readable) way of writing this using tidyr and dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(sport) %>% 
  summarise(medals = sum(medals)) %>% 
  mutate(country = 'Total') ->
  sport_totals

data %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(medals = sum(medals)) %>% 
  mutate(sport = 'Total') ->
  country_totals

data %>% 
  summarise(medals = sum(medals)) %>% 
  mutate(sport = 'Total',
         country = 'Total') ->
  totals

data %>% 
  bind_rows(country_totals, sport_totals, totals) %>% 
  spread(sport, medals)
```

Comment: This is one of those basic things that's ridiculously easy in Excel and WAY(!) too time consuming in R.  Recommend you check out   [rpivotTable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpivotTable/vignettes/rpivotTableIntroduction.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is *the best (compact and readable)* but it works ;)

```
data %>%
  spread(sport, medals) %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[2:4])) %>%
  rbind(., data.frame(country="Total", t(colSums(.[2:5]))))

  country curling crosscountry downhill Total
1  Sweden       0            2        0     2
2  Norway       1            1        0     2
3 Denmark       2            2        1     5
4 Finland       3            0        2     5
5   Total       6            5        3    14
```